# To bridge a UK iPhone hotspot do I need router or modem router

Tags: wireless-networking, iphone

I have an iPhone with unlimited data on Vodafone and I want to share that connection with more devices in the home & home office environment. Like my office PC, printer, then playstation, home TV & other smartphones. There's a problem that the iPhone personal hotspot range is too restricted so I want to boost the range. Also the personal hotspot appears to require a restart to add a new device so I don't actually want devices to connect to the iPhone but connect to a 3rd party router that connects to the iPhone.

To resolve these issues and create a wireless network out of the phone hotspot do I need a modem router or just a router?

Like https://www.asus.com/uk/Networking/DSL-AC88U/ vs https://www.asus.com/uk/Networking/RT-AC86U/

Comment: You can’t bridge it. You can add another level of NAT. You’ll probably find that regular router firmware cannot do what you want (Wi-Fi “WAN” + Wi-Fi “LAN”).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I used Asus AC2900 RT-AC86U router and it does not need a modem to share my iPhone connection.

There were a number of ways to share the internet connection.

If the iPhone is connected to my PC via USB and hotspot is on then per [this question](https://superuser.com/questions/1535138/set-up-internet-connection-sharing-for-windows-7-and-iphone-x-to-share-internet) the router can be setup as an "access point" with a fixed IP to share the connection. With PC on there is also a way to use the router as a "wireless router" without a fixed IP.

However, per [this link](https://netosec.com/tethering-mobile-phone-to-home-network/) if the router is setup as a "repeater" then it can repeat the wireless hotspot on it's own network. This works for my PC at least.

Answer (score 1):

The really unlimited plans from Verizon don’t allow tethering at all,
unless your iPhone is rooted (which I don't recommend).

The following are articles detailing workarounds:

- [How to share Unlimited 4G Data with your Router](https://www.vpnuniversity.com/tutorial/how-to-share-unlimited-4g-data-with-your-router)
  Requires tethering via USB cable and the router must support tethering.
- [iPhone Tethering with Router with DD-WRT](http://www.hagensieker.com/blog/page/?post_id=64&title=iphone-tethering-with-router-with-dd-wrt)
  Requires installing DD-WRT on the router, which does support iPhone tethering.
- [Verizon native tether subscription bypass](https://forum.xda-developers.com/pixel-xl/help/verizon-native-tether-subscription-t3484490)
  Bypass the verizon tether subscription check by installing network signal refresher,
  refresh signal and immediately turn on hotspot while refreshing.

Comment: Also https://netosec.com/tethering-mobile-phone-to-home-network/